# How do I add change the shortcut key to the Shift+A add object menu on the lower left in Blender 2.8 beta?

Tags: customization, shortcut

[image]

How do I add a new keypress option to the Shift+A add object menu on the lower left in Blender 2.82 beta?

Comment: Your question seems a little unclear; what do you mean by 'add a keymap'? Do you want to set a different shortcut for the Shift-A menu? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Better? I made the change.